# NTILE() function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is My Table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ventes](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Région] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[pays] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[CAMensuel] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I want to construct query that returns the sum of CAMensuel. But I have also use NTILE() Function.

I tried to do this query query

```
select*, sum(CAMENSUEL) , NTILE(2)  over(partition by Région order by sum (Région) ) as [ntil] from ventes
```

But that returns this error :
The column 'sales.ID' is not valid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause.

How can I do that please?

Thank you

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. The error *is*, however, telling you the problem, but I suspect a `GROUP BY` on it's own isn't what you're after; as you have a `SELECT *` and thus grouping on every column would be pointless. Perhaps your `SUM` also needs to be windowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is an aggregation query:

```
select v.*,
      sum(CAMENSUEL) ,
       NTILE(2) over (partition by Région order by sum(Région) ) as [ntil]
from ventes v;
```

It contains several errors.  First, using `select *` in an aggregation query is usually an error.  Second, there is no `GROUP BY`.  Third, presumably, `region` is not something that would be aggregated.

I would speculate that you intend something like this:

```
select v.region,
       sum(CAMENSUEL) ,
       NTILE(2) over (order by sum(CAMENSUEL)) as tile
from ventes v
group by region;
```

This aggregates by region and adds a `tile` that is 1 or 2 depending on the sum of `CAMENSUEL`.

Answer (score 0):

Update,
I found the solution

```
select région, Pays ,  sum (CAMENSUEL) over (Partition by Région order by id ) as [SUM_CA_MENSUEL], ntile (2) over(order by id) as NTIL
```

from ventes

Comment: This is because, for whatever reason `NTILE` is not available as an aggregate function, only as a window function. So the `SUM` needs to be also